# Firebase 'requires-recent-login'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to know about firebase `requires-recent-login`.
If I reauthenticate user like this

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(
  firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
  typedpassword))
```

to let user change password or email, is there any possibility that `requires-recent-login` error comes out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some actions require recent authentication and it fails with a `auth/requires-recent-login` error code.

One action that requires recent authentication is the updating of email.

The solution is to [reauthenticate the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user), before retrying the action.

Comment: If `reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` succeed, that doesn't mean recent login?

Comment: The documentation it does not specify which credential should be passed to `reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential()`, is this an email and password, the token?? It's say a prompt, so, I suppose is email and password, am I right?

Comment: correct @DiesanRomero